# how to read only images from a folder?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
class PhotoController {
    def index = {
        def baseFolder = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/").getFile().toString()
        def imagesFolder = baseFolder + '/images/sps'
        def imageList1 = new File(imagesFolder).list()
        [imageList:imageList1]
    }
}
```

The above is listing non-jpg files too. How can I avoid that?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke the [eachFileMatch](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileMatch%28java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) method on the folder:

```
def imageList1 = []
new File(imagesFolder).eachFileMatch(~/.*?\.jpg/) { imageList1 << it }
```

Comment: +1, nice @chris. 1-liner: def l = new File(imagesFolder).eachFileMatch(~/.*?\.jpg/)?.collect{it}

Comment: @virtual that wouldn't work as there's no 1 arg version of `eachFileMatch`... you'd need to do something like: `def imagelist1 = new File( imagesFolder ).listFiles().findAll { it.name ==~ /.*?\.jpg/ }`